# NonlinearModelFit with two-dimensional input to two-dimensional output

Tags: image-processing, fitting

I want to estimate a nonlinear mapping from two-dimensional input positions to two-dimensional output positions.  (Think of this as a nonlinear distortion of an image.  Once I get the estimated function, I can use `ImageForwardTransformation` to perform the transformation on the full image.)

Suppose I have $n$ pairs of "training points":  input $(x_i, y_i)$ to corresponding output $(x_i^\prime , y_i^\prime)$ for $i = 1, \ldots n$.

As a minimum-working example, assume the following two-dimensional data with $n=5$:

```
input = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 2}};
output = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}, {3, 2.5}, {4, 3}};
```

The direct approach to learning the transformation function would be to use `NonlinearModelFit` with (say) different quadratic functions for each of the coordinates.  That is, learn two functions $(x_i^\prime, y_i^\prime) = (f_1(x_i, y_i), f_2(x_i, y_i))$.  The problem is that this approach doesn't adequately incorporate the fact that in the desired true mapping the coordinate mappings are *not* independent.

What I think we really need is to estimate a *single* mapping function from two-dimensional input to two-dimensional output.

Alas, I just couldn't figure out the syntax in `NonlinearModelFit` to achieve this (and apply it to my above sample data).  I have a feeling I'm overlooking some subtlety of syntax in order to get *Mathematica* to learn the desired mapping.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Would that not just be `FindGeometricTransform[output, input]`?

Comment: @MarcoB:  Nope.  That finds a linear (matrix) transformation.

Comment: Markus Van Almsick explains in [this talk](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=104&ob=title&o=ASC&disp=grid&p=21&v=3249) how he **will** use *Radial Basis Functions* to implement interpolating nonlinear image transformation. I suggest to begin to watch at time=25 seconds, mainly to see if it is relevant for you problem (I think it is).

Comment: In his talk he says that the attenders of the conference will have the Notebook with the relevant code (I don't understand what he says very softly just after). I was not there, but I would be happy to have it, if possible.

Comment: Sorry, I mean : " I suggest to begin to watch at time=25 **minutes**"

Comment: @andre314:  Yes... I found the $2D \to 2D$ functionality discussed near the end of the talk.  This is precisely what I need.  Thanks so much for the pointer.  However, I could not find the code for `RadialBasisTransformation`.  Where can I get it?

Comment: See my second comment. I don't know how to get the notebook. I dont understand what he says (nearly inaudibly) at time 26 minutes +30 seconds.

Comment: FYI:  I contacted the author/presenter and requested the code.  We'll see....

Comment: @DavidG.Stork out of curiosity, did you ever hear back from the code author? I was curious to see that code as a well.

Comment: @MarcoB:  Yes... the author graciously provided his code, which I used for my figures.  I don't feel comfortable posting his code without his permission (and it is rather long), but I will say in practice it is a bit tricky to specify the proper inputs and outputs.  In simple cases (such as an image on a barrel ceiling, where the math is simple), it works fine, but in complex cases it often gives small areas of crazy distortions.